# $stateProvider& $urlRouterProvider.otherwise not calling controller of route page

Tags: angularjs

I am new to AngularJS. sorry for long description.
Let me explain my problem here.
Currently I am having initial hit to ASP.net page (default.aspx) define main html contain (header, content, footer). i am loading partial page in content and its working fine as expected. initially i redirect to my dashboard.html using '$urlRouterProvider.otherwise' and its showing me html page but its not calling my dashboard controller hence i am not able to load data as expected but if i click on link having proper route, its working and calling controller.
please find here my snippet.

```html
app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/dashboard');                                

$stateProvider

    // Dashboard
    .state('dashboard', {
        url: "/dashboard",
        templateUrl: "views/a/dashboard.html",
        data: { pageTitle: '', pageSubTitle: '' },
        controller: "dashboardController"            
    })
 .state("Logout", {
        url: "/Logout",
        templateUrl: "views/a/exit.html",
        data: { pageTitle: 'Logout', pageSubTitle: 'User successfully Logout.' }
    })
 .state('profile', {
        url: "/profile",
        templateUrl: "views/a/profile.html",
        data: { pageTitle: '', pageSubTitle: '' },
        controller: "profileController"            
    })
 }]);
```

FYI: controller getting call on click of link.

thanks again.

Comment: technically `url` shouldn;t be `url: "/dashboard.html",` it should be `url: "/dashboard"`

Comment: sorry its type mistake but its define as 'dashboard' but still its not calling controller

Comment: could you put your whole `$stateProvider` state configuration here in your question

Comment: Please update your question by fixing typo.

Comment: updated with typo and full state configuration here

Comment: would be nice if u present ur code in jsFiddle for debugging

Comment: @nukudale Did you fix this? I'm encountering the same problem, and no answers.

Comment: @DanielHigueras it was my silly mistake as i declared controllers separate files and not properly attached app. it resolved after proper app declaration